# Xamarin IMobileServiceTable Run Synchronously

Tags: c#, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

Using the IMobileServiceTable interface, how can I call result of a method synchronously. E.g. GetTask method below :

```
public class ItemsManager {

    IMobileServiceTable<Item> itemTable;
    private ItemViewModel _itemViewModel = new ItemViewModel ();


    public ItemsManager()
    {
        this.itemTable = App.client.GetTable<Item>();
        App.SetItemsManager(this);
    }


    //This seems to just hang
    public Item GetTask(string id, string barcode)
    {

            var qry =  itemTable.Where(a => a.ItemID == id || a.BarCodeID == id);
            return qry.Query.FirstOrDefault();

    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the result via scan method, and extract the item record to another form :

```
async void OnProductScanClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var result = await BarCodes.Instance.Read ();
        if (!result.Success) {
            await this.DisplayAlert ("Scan Failed", "Failed to get barcode", "OK");
        } else {
            var msg = String.Format ("Barcode : {0} - {1}", result.Format, result.Code);
            App.SetItemsManager(new ItemsManager());
            var item = App.ItemManager.GetTask(result.Code, result.Format.ToString());

            if (item == null) {
                await this.DisplayAlert ("Item Not Found!", msg, "OK");
            }
            else {
                var myPage = new ItemsXaml();
                myPage.BindingContext = item;
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync (myPage);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm don't know about xamarin, but for me don't make sense an async void  OnProductScanClicked. Try async Task onProductScanClicked and when invoke the method call with await or OnProductScanClicked.Wait()

Answer (score 0):

I am just new to this stuff, and now have figure out on how to this. We just have to  add the *await* method when calling any asynchronous function.